# verse numbering in gutters

Tags: marginnote

I have the following LaTeX code:

```
\documentclass{book}%
\usepackage[margin=0.75in, paperwidth=6in, paperheight=9in]{geometry}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{marginnote} 

\newcommand{\VS}[1]{{\marginnote{#1}}}
\reversemarginpar

\begin{document}

\VS{1} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, 
consectetur adipiscing elit. consectetur adipiscing elit. 
\VS{2} Nulla erat nibh, elementum non laoreet a, euismod fermentum, euismod
fermentum, euismod fermentum.

\VS{3} Proin sapien nibh, dapibus a enim blandit, finibus scelerisque 
lorem. 
\VS{4} Vestibulum vitae tincidunt lorem. 

\begin{verse}
\VS{5} Roses are red\\
Violets are blue\\
\VS{6} All my base\\
Are belong to you.
\end{verse}

\VS{7} Praesent nibh lacus, tincidunt in tempus a, feugiat nec nibh. 
\end{document}
```

I want the verse numbers to appear in the inner margin (towards the spine). This works great -- except! The baseline of a `marginnote` at the beginning of a paragraph (or verse line) is significantly higher than the baseline of the text line to which it refers. THANKS!

Comment: Welcome! I am afraid that you code will not compile as it stands. Could you please complete it?

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`reledmac`](http://ctan.org/pgk/reledmac) to automate the numbering of the lines. In that case each normal paragraph must be enclosed in  `\pstart`…`\pend` and for verses you can use `\stanza`…`\&`.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{reledmac}
\setcounter{firstlinenum}{1}
\setcounter{linenumincrement}{1}
\setstanzaindents{0,1}
\setcounter{stanzaindentsrepetition}{1}
\linenummargin{inner}
\renewcommand{\numlabfont}{\normalfont\normalsize}

\begin{document}
\beginnumbering
   \pstart
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
   Nulla erat nibh, elementum non laoreet a, euismod fermentum.
   \pend

   \pstart
   Proin sapien nibh, dapibus a enim blandit, finibus scelerisque lorem.
   Vestibulum vitae tincidunt lorem.
   \pend

   \stanza
      Roses are red&
      \skipnumbering Violets are blue&
      All my base&
      \skipnumbering Are belong to you.
   \&

   \pstart
   Praesent nibh lacus, tincidunt in tempus a, feugiat nec nibh.
   \pend
\endnumbering
\end{document}
```

This is also more robust than numbering the lines manually …

Comment: When I build your example, it numbers every single line regardless of newlines in the running text or \skipnumbering. Nevertheless it has put me on the track of the reledmac package, which looks like it will do everything I need  -- and a whole lot more! Time to RTFM those docs...

Comment: You must compile (at least) twice to get the right numbers. Ans in a paragraph every single printed line is numbered by default. In TeX a _new line_ is considered as a space. To get a line break use `\\` for example and an empty line to start a new paragraph …